# loop through a dataframe and append rows from a specific column to a new list when the condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

here is what my code looks like

```
pos_list = []
for i in range(len(df)): 
    if df.loc[i, "sentiment"] == 1:
        pos_list = df.loc[i, "tweets"].tolist()

    else:
        pass
print(pos_list)
```

so if the sentiment == 1 I want to add a row from the tweets column to a list

Comment: kindly share some data and exactly what u want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `append` method:

```
pos_list = []
    for i in range(len(df)): 
    if df.loc[i, "sentiment"] == 1:
        pos_list.append(df.loc[i, "tweets"])

    else:
        pass
print(pos_list)
```

Hope this helps.